# build a library with yocto

Tags: makefile, shared-libraries, static-libraries, yocto

Somewhat new Yocto. Trying to build a library that will be included into the filesystem. I used a [devtool](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#new-recipe-creating-the-base-recipe-using-devtool) to create initial recipe. The library does have a `Makefile` however it (the library) was used in a different project and all the variables, including build and install directories, are tailored towards an original project. Here are a few questions.

1. How do I tell Yocto through a `Makefile` where to build the files for the library?
2. How do I tell Yocto through a `Makefile` where to install the library files?

I have to apologize since I can't post the the source as well as the `Makefile` for the library online due to the nature of the project. But I would really appreciate any pointers or maybe samples of library build instructions for Yocto.

Comment: Probably not the policy of the site to write a complete tutorial. You might have to use pseudo code in order to show where your problems exactly are.

Answer (score 3):

By default yocto recipe have some function to configure, compile and copy the filesand libs to rootfs.

```
do_configure(){
./configure
..
..
}
do_compile(){
make
..
..
}
do_install(){
install -d ${S}${libdir}   # create usr/lib dir in rootfs  
install -d ${S}${libdir}   # create usr/bin dir in rootfs 
install -m 0777 ${S}/lib.so ${D}${libdir}         # copies all your libs to usr/lib
install -m 0777 ${S}/binaries ${D}${bindir}        # copies all your binaries to usr/bin
}
FILES_{PN} +="${libdir}/*"
FILES_{PN} +="${bindir}/*"
```

Note:install means copy
S = yoctosource/build/tme/work/cortex-a8/your package
D = yoctosource/build/tme/work/cortex-a8/image dir for rootfs

Comment: Libraries added that way are not available to pkgconfig?